# Javascript - denormalize JSON array using map function instead of nested for loop

Tags: javascript, json, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I'm trying to get my head around map functions.
Here is my working code and output using a nested for loop:

```
var jsonsToAddTo = [
    {'cat':'k1','key2':'a'},
    {'cat':'k1','key2':'b'},
    {'cat':'k2','key2':'a'},
    {'cat':'k2','key2':'b'},
    {'cat':'k3','key2':'a'}
]

var additionalData = [
    {'pk':'k1','key3':'data1'},
    {'pk':'k2','key3':'data2'},
    {'pk':'k3','key3':'data3'},
]

// Adds a key value pair from sourceJson to targetJson based on a matching value
function denormalizeJsonOnKey(targetJsonArray,targetKeyToMatch, sourceJsonArray, sourceKeyToMatch, keyToAdd){
    for(thisJson in targetJsonArray){
        for(thatJson in sourceJsonArray){
            if(targetJsonArray[thisJson][targetKeyToMatch]==sourceJsonArray[thatJson][sourceKeyToMatch]){
                console.log('match');
                targetJsonArray[thisJson][keyToAdd]=sourceJsonArray[thatJson][keyToAdd];
            }
        }
    }
    return targetJsonArray
}

console.log(denormalizeJsonOnKey(jsonsToAddTo,'cat',additionalData,'pk','key3'))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[ 
    { cat: 'k1', key2: 'a', key3: 'data1' },
    { cat: 'k1', key2: 'b', key3: 'data1' },
    { cat: 'k2', key2: 'a', key3: 'data2' },
    { cat: 'k2', key2: 'b', key3: 'data2' },
    { cat: 'k3', key2: 'a', key3: 'data3' } 
]
```

I can't figure out how to handle the nesting using a map function on an array.

Comment: dawg....... Do Array Cardio Day 1 and 2. It will change your life. https://javascript30.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,
using  `maps` for both iteration,

```js
var jsonsToAddTo = [{'cat':'k1','key2':'a'},{'cat':'k1','key2':'b'}, 
                   {'cat':'k2','key2':'a'},{'cat':'k2','key2':'b'},    
                   {'cat':'k3','key2':'a'}]


var additionalData = [{'pk':'k1','key3':'data1'},{'pk':'k2','key3':'data2'},{'pk':'k3','key3':'data3'},
]


function denormalizeJsonOnKey(targetJsonArray,targetKeyToMatch, sourceJsonArray, sourceKeyToMatch, keyToAdd){
    
      jsonsToAddTo.map((obj,index)=> {
        additionalData.map((o,idx)=> {  
            if(obj[targetKeyToMatch]==o[sourceKeyToMatch]){
              obj[keyToAdd]=o[keyToAdd];
            }
         })
       })
      return jsonsToAddTo
    }
    console.log(denormalizeJsonOnKey(jsonsToAddTo,'cat',additionalData,'pk','key3'))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using ES6 can simplify using `Array#find()` and `Object#assign()`

```js
var data = [
    {'cat':'k1','key2':'a'},
    {'cat':'k1','key2':'b'},
    {'cat':'k2','key2':'a'},
    {'cat':'k2','key2':'b'},
    {'cat':'k3','key2':'a'}
]

var data2 = [
    {'pk':'k1','key3':'data1'},
    {'pk':'k2','key3':'data2'},
    {'pk':'k3','key3':'data3'},
]

const mergeData= (arr1, arr2, matchKey, filterKey, includeKey)=>{
   arr1.forEach(o => {
      const newObj ={};
      const match = arr2.find(e => e[filterKey] === o[matchKey])
      newObj[includeKey] = match ? match[includeKey] : null;  
      Object.assign(o, newObj);
   });
}

mergeData(data, data2,'cat', 'pk', 'key3')

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that takes advantage of `map` and object spread to produce a new array with the desired key added into the target array's elements:

```js
var jsonsToAddTo = [
    {'cat':'k1','key2':'a'},
    {'cat':'k1','key2':'b'},
    {'cat':'k2','key2':'a'},
    {'cat':'k2','key2':'b'},
    {'cat':'k3','key2':'a'}
]

var additionalData = [
    {'pk':'k1','key3':'data1'},
    {'pk':'k2','key3':'data2'},
    {'pk':'k3','key3':'data3'},
]

function denormalizeJsonOnKey(targetJsonArray,targetKeyToMatch, sourceJsonArray, sourceKeyToMatch, keyToAdd){
    return targetJsonArray.map(thisJson => {
        const addObj = sourceJsonArray.find(thatJson => thatJson[sourceKeyToMatch] === thisJson[targetKeyToMatch]);
        return {
            ...thisJson,
            ...addObj ? {[keyToAdd]: addObj[keyToAdd]} : {},
        }
    });
}

console.log(denormalizeJsonOnKey(jsonsToAddTo, 'cat', additionalData, 'pk', 'key3'))
```

Note that this solution won't mutate the original array, so the `jsonsToAddTo` variable will be the same after you invoke the function. If you want to replace the original, you can always just re-assign it:

```
jsonsToAddTo = denormalizeJsonOnKey(jsonsToAddTo, 'cat', additionalData, 'pk', 'key3')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var targetJsonArray = jsonsToAddTo.map(function(json, index) {
    additionalData.forEach(function(data) {
        if (data.pk === json.cat) {
            json.key3 = data.key3;
        }
    })
    return json;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than nesting loops here, which will iterate the entire `additionalData` array for every entry in `jsonsToAddTo`, I suggest building an object map of the `additionalData` dataset **once** at the beginning, and then reference this within a .map on the target dataset:

```
var jsonsToAddTo = [
    {'cat':'k1','key2':'a'},
    {'cat':'k1','key2':'b'},
    {'cat':'k2','key2':'a'},
    {'cat':'k2','key2':'b'},
    {'cat':'k3','key2':'a'}
]

var additionalData = [
    {'pk':'k1','key3':'data1'},
    {'pk':'k2','key3':'data2'},
    {'pk':'k3','key3':'data3'},
]

// Adds a key value pair from sourceJson to targetJson based on a matching value
function denormalizeJsonOnKey(targetJsonArray,targetKeyToMatch, sourceJsonArray, sourceKeyToMatch, keyToAdd){
    // Build an object of items keyed on sourceKeyToMatch
    const sourceJsonMap = sourceJsonArray.reduce((obj, item) => (obj[item[sourceKeyToMatch]]=item, obj), {});
    return targetJsonArray.map(item => {
        const targetValue = item[targetKeyToMatch];
        if (sourceJsonMap.hasOwnProperty(targetValue)) {
        item[keyToAdd] = sourceJsonMap[targetValue][keyToAdd];
      }
      return item;
    });
}

console.log(denormalizeJsonOnKey(jsonsToAddTo,'cat',additionalData,'pk','key3'))
```

Doing it this way should be far more efficient, especially if the dataset you are working on is fairly large.